# How to create a map by switching keys and values from another map in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Given the map of objects that contains a list of repeating strings:

```
variable "input_var" = {
  type = object(map(
    name = string
    tags = optional(list(string))
  )),
  default = {
    "one" = {
      name = "nameone"
      tags = ["tag1", "tag2"]
    }
    "two" = {
      name = "nametwo"
      tags = ["tag1", "tag3"]
    }
    "three" = {
      name = "namethree"
      tags = ["tag2"]
    }
    "four" = { 
      name = "namefour"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a map with keys being the tags from all elements of `var.input_var`.
Taking the above defaults, a sample of output is:

```
{
  "tag1": [
    {
      name = "nameone"
      key = "one"
    },
    {
      name = "nametwo"
      key = "two"
    },
  ],
  "tag2": [
    {
      name = "namethree"
      key = "three"
    }
  ],
  "tag3": [
    {
      name = "nametwo"
      key = "two"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was able to achieve this in a two step steps.

First is to create a unique set of tags:

```
locals{
  tags_set = distinct(flatten([
    for k, v in var.input_var: coalesce(v.tags, [])
  ]))
}
```

followed by creating the (local) map out of `local.tags_set`:

```
tags_map = { for key_tag in local.tags_set:
    key_tag => flatten([for k, v in var.input_var: [
      for tag in coalesce(v.tags, []) : {
        key = k
        name = v.name
      } if tag == key_tag
  ]]) }
```

Is there a better implementation for this, in a single step and/or more efficient?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: @Marcin nothing is wrong. I am a beginner in Terraform and created this so I am thinking there must be a better/cleaner way that I am not aware of (as a beginner).